# android can not get built jwPlayer maven repository

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

When I try to build my android application, It does not get built due to an error from `JwPlayer` in maven repository.

I got the following error:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.
<a href="openFile:/home/masoudkh/AndroidStudioProjects/Tootak/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+.">Show Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the SSL Certificate had expired for mvn.jwplayer.com. It is now back online as I have successfully built my Android Studio project with Maven.

For future reference, you can always use the AAR’s to build your Android Studio Project available in your JW Player Dashboard or use the HTTP version of our Maven domain.

```
maven {
    url 'http://mvn.jwplayer.com/content/repositories/releases/'
}
```